# Format time from miliseconds to show only the date

Tags: java

Sorry if my question has already been answered, but I can't really find what I am looking for.
So I have this time "1228061700000" and I want to convert it to show only the date, like this 17/6/08.
It would also be good to check for the locale, so for US locale the format to be like this 6/17/08 and for european locale to be 17/6/08... How can I do it?

Comment: some code would be helpful...

Comment: You need to convert from "1228061700000" or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I need to convert from many such dates, so I just need a good example to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long milliSeconds=1228061700000l;
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  //change your date time formate as required
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: Calendar is expensive, I wouldn't set a Calendar just to get a Date from it. Try `new Date(millisSeconds)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use a DateFormat:

```
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
String result = f.format(new Date(millis));
```

Comment: I dont want to use deprecated methods

Answer (score 2):

[DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale aLocale)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)This displays the current date in a locale-specific way.

So, you can try:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, yourLocale);
String formattedDate = df.format(yourDate);
```

In this case you can choose what type of `yourDate` is.
Your locate can be changed to `Locale.UK` `Locale.US` and etc.